# How to map new array of objects out of observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a response from HttpClient in the form of a JSON object. In my observable, I am trying to use RXJS methods to get the data I need.

The data I need is an array of objects on the response object. I use `pluck` to get the array out of the response object and that works fine. However, when I try to map the result, I am getting the error `Property map does not exist on type {}`. I am trying to map the array of objects to another array of objects.

Here is the core of the observable piping:

```
.pipe(
    switchMap(data => this._settingsService.getSortPlan(data.plan, data.sorter)),
    pluck('sortPlanRoutes'),
    map(planRoutes => planRoutes.map(this.mapSortPlans))
)
```

And the map function:

```
private mapSortPlans(plan) {
    return {
        route: plan.sortDestination.sortDestination,
        locationType: plan.physicalLocationAttribute.attrValue,
        destination: plan.physicalLocation.locationAlias,
        priority: plan.priority
    };
}
```

I expect the `map(planRoutes => planRoutes.map(this.mapSortPlans))` to be able to run the `mapSortPlans` function, but it's giving me the error `Property map does not exist on type {}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right way, but I was able to cast `planRoutes` to an array:

```
switchMap(data => this._settingsService.getSortPlan(data.plan, data.sorter)),
pluck('sortPlanRoutes'),
map(planRoutes => (planRoutes as Array<any>).map(this.mapSortPlans))
```

That got rid of the error.

Comment: You can put a `console.log()` inside the `map` operator to see if `planRoutes` is really an array. That should give you an idea of what you're trying to iterate over.

Comment: @DzhavatUshev I did and it's showing it as an array.

Comment: It seems like the type gets lost somewhere in the functions so the compiler doesn't detect the `planRoutes` as an array. You can also do `map((planRoutes: any[]) => planRoutes.map(this.mapSortPlans))`, which will tell the TypeScript compiler that `planRoutes` is in fact an array.